# Set CI/CD variables depending on environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

We have multiple environments (staging, production...) and I don't want to put sentitive informations like database passwords inside the codebase. For this, I want to use environment variables provided by GitLab CI/CD.

However I don't know how to tell GitLab to run a different set of variables depending on my environment.

What I've done so far:

1- Create environments : Via UI (**Project => Operations => Environments** : Here I created 2 environments, `STAGING` and `PRODUCTION`

2- Create variables Via UI (**Project => Settings => CI/CD => Variables** : Here I created the variable `DB_PASSWORD` twice (with of course different values assigned) , one with *environment scope* set to `STAGING`, the other one to `PRODUCTION`.

Now what I want to do is run my project's pipeline. So I go to **Project => CI/CD => Pipelines => Run Pipeline** and here I expect GitLab CI to ask me if I would like to run my pipeline with the set of variables set for STAGING or PRODUCTION but it doesn't.

How I am supposed to tell GitLab that I want to run my pipeline using **DB_PASSWORD** variable with the value corresponding to the environment I want to target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the environment in your gitlab-ci.yml file, see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#configuring-environments)

**Example from official gitlab docs**:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script: echo "Running tests"

build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building the app"

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  only:
    - master
```

In this example when running `deploy_staging` the environment is set to `staging` and thus you can access the defined Variables for the environment, like so:

```yaml
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  variables:
    DB_PASS: ${DB_PASSWORD}              # which is your defined variable within Gitlab CI
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: So am I to understand that one has to duplicate all the jobs across the different environments? It is not possible to use environments to simply trigger different behaviour in one set of jobs?

Comment: this would be possible using matrix jobs for different environments. 
Alternatively you can abstract a job into a template block which can be hydrated with variables